# How to show or hide a label using jquery

Tags: jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following code.

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label labelfont">FIRST NAME:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
               <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter the First Name" id="FirstName">
            </div>
            <label class="col-sm-2 labelfont errorMsg" id="Err_FirstName">Enter the first name</label>
        </div>
```

Initially `"Err_FirstName"` is hidden.If the input field is empty on tabout,I want the `error label` to be displayed.

I have written the following code in blur event.

```
$("#FirstName").on("blur", function () {
    if ($(this).val().trim().length == 0) {
        $("#Err_FirstName").show();
    }
    else {
        $("#Err_FirstName").hide();
    }
});
```

the `'errormsg'` class is defined as

```
.errorMsg {
   display:none;        
   color:Red;
}
```

The label is not getting displayed on tabout.Could someone point me in the right direction,in case I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Works for me. http://jsfiddle.net/7sb76fqw/

Comment: It works perfectly fine. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tfqmr0ty/). What is your issue?

Comment: This could be an Internet Explorer issue based on which version of jQuery you're using (if you're testing in IE) - http://api.jquery.com/blur/

Comment: its working check [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jxds8qhn/2/)

Comment: I am checking in Firefox.The issue is that on tabout,I dont get the error message and the focus moves to the next control.

Comment: jik_charles . Your fiddle code is not working,which is exactly the issue that I am facing.I adont see the error label on tabout if the text input is empty.

Answer (score 4):

The code perfectly works for me. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RaginiGurram/mqj3wd58/2/).

```js
$("#FirstName").on("blur", function () {
    if ($(this).val().trim().length == 0) {
        $("#Err_FirstName").show();
    }
    else {
        $("#Err_FirstName").hide();
    }
});
```

```css
.errorMsg {
   display:none;        
   color:Red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label labelfont">FIRST NAME:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
               <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter the First Name" id="FirstName">
            </div>
            <label class="col-sm-2 labelfont errorMsg" id="Err_FirstName">Enter the first name</label>
        </div>
```

May be worth checking jQuery version you are using .for this code snippet i am using jQuery 1.9.1 .The Best practice to do this is having another class and change the class name if there is no value in the FirstName.